# How can I get true if we compare a to á?

Tags: c#, string

I'm studying `string.Normalize()` method and I thought it is used to compare string equality if they are using different unicode.

Here's what I've done so far. Is the `string.Equals()` is not what I'm supposed to use here?

```
        string stra = "á";
        string straNorm = stra.Normalize();
        string strFormC = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        string strFormD = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        string strFormKC = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
        string strFormKD = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);
        Console.WriteLine("norm {0}",straNorm);
        Console.WriteLine("C {0}", strFormC);
        Console.WriteLine("D {0}", strFormD);
        Console.WriteLine("KC {0}", strFormKC);
        Console.WriteLine("KD {0}", strFormKD);

        Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(stra)); //false
        Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(straNorm)); //false
        Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(stra.Normalize())); //false
        Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(strFormC)); //false
        Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(strFormKC)); //false
        Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(strFormKD)); //false
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288114/what-does-nets-string-normalize-do or https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html help your understanding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `string.Compare()` setting `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and  `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace` as you can see below I have created a method called `CompareStrings(string str1, string str2)`, it will return a `boolean`

```
public bool CompareStrings(string str1, string str2)
{
    return string.Compare(str1, str2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0; 
}
```

Calling the method to compare strings:

```
Console.WriteLine(CompareStrings("a", "á"));
Console.WriteLine(CompareStrings("a", "a"));
Console.WriteLine(CompareStrings("a", "b"));
```

Results:

> `True`
>   `True`
>   `False`

The `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace` definition: It "indicates that the string comparison must ignore nonspacing combining characters, such as diacritics. The Unicode Standard defines combining characters as characters that are combined with base characters to produce a new character. Nonspacing combining characters do not occupy a spacing position by themselves when rendered."

You can find out more about `CompareOptions` on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 5):

After normalization in forms D and KD, the string will contain two characters: a letter and a diacritical character. It is necessary to make a comparison with the letter.

```
string stra = "á";

string strFormC = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
string strFormD = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
string strFormKC = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
string strFormKD = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);

Console.WriteLine("C {0}", strFormC.Length); // 1
Console.WriteLine("D {0}", strFormD.Length); // 2
Console.WriteLine("KC {0}", strFormKC.Length); // 1
Console.WriteLine("KD {0}", strFormKD.Length); // 2

Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(strFormD[0].ToString())); // True
Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(strFormKD[0].ToString())); // True
```

---

We can remove all diacritical characters with a regular expression.

`\p{M}` - is [Unicode category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories) means All diacritic marks.

```
string stra = "á";

string strFormD = stra.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

var result = Regex.Replace(strFormD, @"\p{M}", string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine("a".Equals(result)); // True
Console.WriteLine("a" == result); // True
```