# Match Vietnamese names with and without diacritics in C#

Tags: c#, string-comparison, diacritics

I had written a code where i want to compare 2 same names but one is with diacritics

eg. Dăn will match with Dan

I want to be able to match Vietnamese names with and without diacritics but my code keep returns not matching for the checking. Is there any other way to do this?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name1 = "Dan";
        string name2 = "Dăn";

        bool match = CompareStrings(name1, name2);

        if (match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The strings match.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The strings do not match.");
        }
    }

    static bool CompareStrings(string str1, string str2)
    {
        if (str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        string str1Normalized = str1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        string str2Normalized = str2.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);

        if (str1Normalized.Equals(str2Normalized, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288164

Comment: There is an extremely simple solution in the duplicate (not the accepted answer): String.Compare(name1, name2, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0.

Comment: Yes, @PalleDue that indeed works for my question, thanks alot!